# Python code not screening out future dates with datetime comparison

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-views

I am having a strange issue when trying to screen out future dates from an API endpoint of the application. I have the following tournaments with 1 tournament listed an hour in the future (tourney 8):

[image]

I have the following model:

```
class Tournament(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I have the following view:

```
def get_current_tournaments(request, player_id):
    registration_queryset = TournamentRegistration.objects.filter(player=player_id)
    active_tournaments = []
    for registration in registration_queryset:
        tournament = registration.tournament
        if tournament.active:
            utc=pytz.UTC
            start_time = tournament.start_time.replace(tzinfo=utc)
            if start_time > datetime.now(start_time.tzinfo):
                active_tournaments.append(tournament.pk)
    print(active_tournaments)
    return JsonResponse({'tournament_ids': active_tournaments})
```

Every time I call the `get_current_tournamnents()` view I get a list of ALL the tourneys a player is registered for, including ones in the future (tourney 8 is in the future). My expectation was that `if start_time > datetime.now(start_time.tzinfo):` would screen out future times and only include currently active tournaments, i.e. tourneys that have already started (start_time is in the past).

```
HTTP GET /tournaments/current-tournaments/1/ 200 [0.02, 127.0.0.1:55555]
[2, 1, 4, 6, 5, 7, 8]
```

This list above includes tourney 8, which is in the future as of right now.

Now when I change that line to `if start_time < datetime.now(start_time.tzinfo):`, so if start_time is less than now, it screens out all tournaments and I get an empty list, when I expected to only get the tournament in the future. I am confused about what I'm doing wrong and am not very versed in specifics of datetimes.

Comment: I'm not sure why you have this loop. Why not just get the active events in the query: `Tournament.objects.filter(tournamentregistration__player=player_id, start_time__lte=datetime.now())`?

Comment: Why are you doing all that timezone stuff? Are you not using `USE_TZ = True`?

Comment: Kevin where would i use USE_TZ= True...in the model?

Comment: Ty Daniel that query worked for me

Comment: That's a setting (in the settings file) that enables timezone support. With it enabled you get timezone-aware `datetime` objects, which Python knows how to compare without you doing any explicit conversions like you are here. See the [timezone documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/) for more.